# structuring REST api for RAILS app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rest

We have a mixed html and api app. We chose to split the standard html part into regular controllers and put the api into api_CONTROLLER_NAME. So we have an items_controller.rb and an api_items_controller.rb. We use jquery  to post updates and creating of items. HOWEVER, we post to a single end-point /api/items and based upon whether there is an id in the params determine whether a new item should be created or an item should be updated. I'm pretty uncomfortable with this and think that we should post to create and put to update but since browser support is somehwat iffy in terms of put and delete, the argument is we should do it this way.

So I have two questions: (1) Is splitting between two controllers bad design? Or should we have it go through a single controller? I personally feel two controllers is fine. (2) Is doing creates and updates in a single method ok or should we split them out and, is the argument about browser support somewhat bogus? We only need to support IE8 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I usually code my api within its own namespace because its logic is different from the core logic. So having different controllers sounds good to me

2) if you claim to use REST, use REST. So split create and update. Dont worry about the browser. FYI, Rails itself cheats the PUT with a hidden field in the forms (`_method`)

Comment: thx, I agree with both points. The PUT would be for a XHR api call so no form involved but will go this way as I think it makes it much more understandable. I probably wasn't clear in asking question. thx again

Comment: Just be aware you can so a PoST with a hidden field and Rails will understand it as a PUT